# How to curve fit data to a known formula with two independence variables?

Tags: math, curve-fitting

Suppose I have a nonlinear formula like y = (ax + bx^2 + cx^3) * dx1^2

Where a,b,c,d are coefficients to be found and x and x1 are data in a table I am trying to fit.

I need an optimization algorithm I can write in code (e.g C or Delphi) to run through an iteration to get reasonable coefficients a,b,c,d.

Don't want to use Matlab or packages as this must be a stand alone program. Reference to a delphi or active X unit is helpful. Don't mind to pay for the software if I can use it freely.

Comment: So, your data table contains multiple triples `(x, dx1, y)` and you want to find the coefficients `a, b, c`? This is perfectly linear (in the unknowns). Thus, you can formulate a [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) problem and solve it.

Comment: Note that if the last operator is really a product you do not need `d`, that is already in `a`, `b`, and `c`

Comment: I suggest researching "multiple linear regression" in the programming language of choice, you can then format x, x^2, and (x^3 * x1^2 in the code and linearly regress that to get a, b, and c. An offset parameter is often useful, for that format 1.0 (offset times 1) in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is linear in a, b, c and d even if it is cubic in the data. Therefore I would suggest formulating this as an [ordinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) problem. Allow me to rename your x1 to z. The idea is this: you have

ax<sub>i</sub> + bx<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + cx<sub>i</sub><sup>3</sup> + dz<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> ≈ y<sub>i</sub>

for some i∈{1,2,3…n}. You can write that as an approximate matrix equation:

```
⎡x₁ x₁² x₁³ z₁²⎤   ⎡a⎤   ⎡y₁⎤
⎢x₂ x₂² x₂³ z₂²⎥   ⎢b⎥   ⎢y₂⎥
⎢x₃ x₃² x₃³ z₃²⎥ ∙ ⎢c⎥ ≈ ⎢y₃⎥
⎢ ⋮ ⋮  ⋮  ⋮ ⎥   ⎣d⎦   ⎢⋮⎥
⎣xₙ xₙ² xₙ³ zₙ²⎦         ⎣yₙ⎦
```

Or more shortly

M ∙ X ≈ Y

Now you [multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) both sides with the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of that matrix M:

M<sup>T</sup> ∙ M ∙ X = M<sup>T</sup> ∙ Y

Notice that I changed from ≈ to = because the least squares solution will satisfy this modified equation exactly (for lengthy reasons I don't want to go into here). This is a simple 4×4 system of linear equations. Solve using common techniques (such as [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)) to find X=(a,b,c,d).

If n is large you can even compute (M<sup>T</sup> ∙ M) and (M<sup>T</sup> ∙ Y) on the fly without ever storing M itself. That way 4×4+4=20 numbers will be all the memory you need to maintain between input records. Actually (M<sup>T</sup> ∙ M) is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) so 10 numbers are enough for the matrix, 14 in total.

Comment: uhhh, that version is slightly oversimplified.

Comment: @mikuszefski: Oversimplified in what way? I left out all the rationale as to *why* this works, or the discussion as to what this actually optimizes. But for the question at hand as to “how do I get reasonable coefficients” I feel it does the job. But I'l be very interested to read your take on this, so feel free to write an independent or complimentary answer.

Comment: well, after teaching for more than a decade I can only say that the right result does not mean that the answer is right. Least square means that you have a vector `E` such that `M k = Y + E` where `k` is the coefficient vector. After minimizing `E_T E` with respect to `k` you get `M_T M k_opt = M_T Y`. In this sense your answer is right but the reason is...uhhh...oversimplified....Although, I guess that you know that.

Comment: @mikuszefski: I didn't even mean to claim to *have* an explanation. Just instructions, recipe style. In terms of explanation I prefer the geometric view, of orthogonal projection from Y onto the space spanned by M, but that would take some more work to elaborate, and would not be the right mindset for everyone either.

Comment: ..agreed...I just was irritated by the statement *Now you multiply both sides with the transpose of that matrix M, and you can aim for equality* as this sort of implies that this is the reason/right way of doing it; never mind.

Comment: @mikuszefski: Thanks, now I see how that phrase was misleading. I changed that bit, hope this is less ambiguous now.